# why is hugepage not getting updated

Tags: dpdk, huge-pages

I am getting this error

> EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB

So, even after setting the nr_hugepages I am not able to see the updated/set value. What could be the reason

```
root@vpp-dut:/opt/trs/vpp_src# cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
0

root@vpp-dut:/opt/trs/vpp_src# echo 1024 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages

root@vpp-dut:/opt/trs/vpp_src# cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
0

root@vpp-dut:~# cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:         0 kB

HugePages_Total:    1024

HugePages_Free:     1024

HugePages_Rsvd:        0

HugePages_Surp:        0

Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Answer (score 2):

> EAL: No free hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB

That's not an error, but merely a warning that you don't have any free 1GB hugepage. It will become an issue if you also have this message for 2MB hugepages. According to `/proc/meminfo`, you do have free 2MB hugepages (`Hugepagesize: 2048 kB`). **DPDK only needs either 1GB or 2MB hugepages, not both**.

If your application fails to start, the root cause is somewhere else.

Comment: when I run DPDK it always checks for /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages this instead of checking this /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages which has 1024 set

Comment: Do you mean that the application fails to start because of that? Could you add the error messages to your question?

Comment: application was not starting because of some other error, thanks

Comment: Oh, nice to know you found the issue! Is there something you want me to change to accept the answer?